# significance of Burton number theory exercise

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is the question in Burton - I can solve it but am not sure what the importance of this exercise is and what Burton is trying to help me see with it:

Find a prime divisor of the integer $N=4(3*7*11) - 1$ of the form $4n+3$.

Do the same for $N = 4(3*7*11*15)-1$

I can see the solution is

$N = 4(3*7*11) - 1 = 923 = 13*71$

$71 = 4*17 + 3$ is of the required form

$N = 4(3*7*11*15)-1 = 13859$.

By trial division or prime table lookup, etc. $13859$ is prime.
$13859 = 4*3464 + 3$ is of the required form.

The fact that $N$ is broken down into the forms they are makes me think there is something I am missing.  I note that 3,7,11,15 are all of form 4k+3 which I think is related.  Similarly, $N$ are both of form $4k + 3$ since for example $4(3*7*11*15) - 1 = 4(3*7*11*15) - 4 + 3 = 4(3*7*11*15 - 1) + 3$

Why did Burton include such an exercise - is there some more elegant way to solve these types of problems?

Comment: At a guess:  it's interesting to note that any number of the form $4k-1$ must have a prime factor of the form $4n+3$.  That's because multiplying a bunch of primes of the form $4k+1$ can only give you numbers of the form $4k+1$.  This exercise just encourages you to find the factor explicitly.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. It is reinforcing the idea of Theorem 3-6 that there are an infinite number of primes of form 4k+3 which uses the idea you mention in the proof.

Comment: I assume the text also points out that it is surprisingly difficult to show that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4k+1$.  Perfectly possible, of course, but this nice trick doesn't work.

Comment: The text says "one might reasonably ask: is the number of primes of the form 4n + 1 also infinite? This answer is likewise in the affirmative, but a demonstration must await the development of the necessary mathematical machinery. Both these results are special cases of a remarkable theorem by Dirichlet on primes in arithmetic progression established in 1837. The proof is much too difficult for inclusion here so that we content ourselves with the mere statement..."
He then give's Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Oh, that's overkill.  It's surprisingly difficult, but not as hard as that.  Do you know about quadratic residues?

Comment: I don't know about quadratic residues but it looks like Burton covers them in a later chapter. I'm going straight through doing all the exercises so will get there eventually. My study time is rather limited unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a proof that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4k-1.$

Comment: 4k-1 = 4(k-1) + 3 and Burton already provides a theorem in the chapter that primes of this form are infinite in number. I guess this is reinforcing that in another way.